# Typegraphql type definition

Tags: typegraphql

i have a mutation in my resolver where the return type is defined as Post

```
@Mutation(()=>Post)
    // some code logique 
    }
```

- How i can change it to be (Post|string)?

Answer (score 0):

After reading i found that it could be done by creating an ObjectType and makes it fields optional like this:

```
@ObjectType()
class Postresponce {

@Field(type => Post, {nullable:true})
post?:Post

@Field(type=>String ,{nullable:true})
errorMessage?:String
}
```

and use it in my Mutation like this:

```
@Mutation(type => Postresponce)
```